# How do I apply the colors of the blood moon over my high res moon image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I took multiple shots of the moon to compile this stacked image:

[image]

On the same night, I also took this photo of the blood moon:

[image]

How do I apply the color of the second picture onto the first to produce a high res blood moon shot?

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that I tried to use "Overlay" but it ended up looking really bad:

[image]

Comment: Many different ways to do it, here's one: https://youtu.be/ECDmGI3L5Kw?t=411 — Found it by googling: `photoshop tutorial blood moon`

Comment: What have you tried? Where is that failing?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method

1. Open the orange-coloured image, then paste the black and white image on a layer above, making sure they are both aligned.
2. Use the Dodge and Burn tools with a large-soft edged brush selected, and create highlights and shadows on the moon.

[image]

3. Set the layer blending mode to *Luminosity*

[image]

4. If you think the highlight area looks a bit desaturated, sample the orange colour with the eyedropper, and on the background layer, using a large soft-edge Paint Brush and opacity set to around 25%, paint some colour back in the highlight area. It doesn't matter if you go over the edges of the moon when painting.

Here's the final result

[image]

Comment: i think the red image could also be used to generate a gradient map

Comment: @Luciano how could I do that?

Comment: @Tinker I don't know exactly, but you can google "Photoshop gradient map" and go from there.